# Redirection to https not working using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, octobercms

I have created a environment for my application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have enabled https using the load balancer configuration. I want to redirect traffic from http to https. I have tried all of the following method but it is not working.

1) I created a .ebextensions folder in my project root directory with the file name as https-redirect-php.config.

2)The content of the file was pasted from the following file.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/php/https-redirect-php.config.

3)I created the zip of the folder and deployed it on the server.

4)I also tried using the eb cli command eb deploy but it is not working.

Please suggest me any help. I would be really thankful

Comment: i am not sure it is not relevant to october-cms i guess

Comment: Yes I think the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution consists to add to your `.ebextensions` directory a config file with the following lines :

```
option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: HTTPS
```

Take a look at [Configuring Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Load Balancer to Terminate HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html)

Comment: I will try this out and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ELASTIC BEANSTALK -> CONFIGURATION -> LOAD BALANCER -> RULES

After you have your ports and your Certificate try to add this rules:

[image]